# Separating Faces from an Image

Tags: java, android, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I am currently working with Firebase ML Kit on Android. I want to save faces from an image on detection (let's say an image has 3 detected faces). How can this be achieved programmatically?
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: As an assumption: the model gives you pairs of (x, y) on the image (rectandles) where it detects faces, then you copy image data from those coordinates (rectangles) into new images

Comment: This has resolved the issue. Thanks